# Replace maven library with local one

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a dependency in pom on some library.
I want to make some changes in it, test it locally and if it will work fine - deploy it to remote repo.
So I have locally made some changes in this library, installed it as a jar, and want to replace in my main project remote library with the local one.

What is proper way to do it?

Comment: Depends. Do you use Nexus or Artifactory? Is this your own library (or a third party library)? What kind of build tool are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project]

Comment: Note that the Maven mindset is that non-SNAPSHOT artifacts are in general frozen and any copy is as good as any other so caches may be disruptive and your builds will not be reproducible. This mean, either use SNAPSHOTs or be very careful what you do.  Creating a new artifact may be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override default maven repository in project's pom:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>file://d:/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Answer (score 3):

When resolving dependencies, Maven looks in your local repository (`$HOME/.m2/repository`). So if you have installed your modified dependency into your local repository (e.g. through `mvn install`) then when you build your main project, it will be used.

To make this more obvious, you may want to change the versions being used in both the library and your main project POM, so that you can be sure your version is being used for testing.

You may also find this question/answer useful: [How do I force Maven to use my local repository rather than going out to remote repos to retrieve artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548395)

Answer (score 2):

Maven first looks in your local repository in

`C:\Users\User\.m2\repository`

and if it can't find the library, then it looks in remote repos. If I understand your question correctly, this should be happening automatically as long as you point the correct version in the POM.

Answer (score 0):

#### Make library changes reflect in consuming project

Assuming you are working on a library named `lib-some-util-service`, and importing the same in your `project-using-lib` locally:

1. After making the appropriate changes in the `lib-some-util-service`, run the *mvn install* command to install the library updating the changes locally.

   mvn install
2. Navigate to your `project-using-lib` *POM* file.
3. Point the `lib-some-util-service` to the righ version. Since you were developing locally and probably not deployed, the version name could be something like `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`. You can confirm the latest version in your `.m2` folder.
4. Now *ReBuild* the `project-using-lib`. This will pick the updated library and you will see the new changes from the `project-using-lib`