# locally installed jar dependency in github action

Tags: maven, spring-boot, java-11, github-actions

In my maven project, I'm creating a jar locally and specifying it in pom as a dependency. In GitHub action install step is working `mvn install:install-file` and it is installing jar at location `/root/.m2/repository/`.
But in the next command to run tests `mvn clean test` it's checking that dependency in maven central and failing. How do we use dependency locally installed in case of GitHub action?

Comment: First of all, when you build a jar, you should usually call `mvn install` instead of `mvn install:install`. If the jar is external, use `mvn install:install-file`. Futhermore, I would check whether the local repository "survives" to the next maven call and is really the same.

Comment: Changes to the workspace should persist between job steps, but not between jobs. If the dependency is there in the next step and it's still failing, then maybe this answer will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548395/how-do-i-force-maven-to-use-my-local-repository-rather-than-going-out-to-remote/33584084#33584084

Comment: @JFMeier yeah my bad, updated the question, I was using mvn install:install-file only.