# Maven (IntelliJ) always using remote repository for artifacts

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 maven projects where one depends on another. Let's call them `common` and `service`.

`service` specifically depends on a module within `common` we'll call `common-module`.

If I make an update to `common-module` and run `mvn clean install`, it gets properly installed to my **local** repository.

#### Problem

In `service`, when I do a `mvn clean package/install` or `mvn -U clean package/install` will pick up the version that's in the **remote** repository even though the one I just built is newer. I cannot get it to pick up that latest version even though I see it in my `.m2/repository`.

How can I get it to pick my locally built jar?

#### Setup

`pom.xml` for `common` (simplified, a lot is excluded)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  
    <artifactId>common-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.4.5-SNAPSHOT</version>  
    <name>Common Parent</name>  
    <modules>  
        <module>common-module</module>  
    </modules>
</project>
```

`pom.xml` for `common-module` (simplified, a lot is excluded)

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
    <artifactId>common-module</artifactId>  
    <name>common-module</name>  
    <description>common-module</description>  
    <parent>  
        <artifactId>common-parent</artifactId>  
        <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>  
        <version>2.4.5-SNAPSHOT</version>  
    </parent>
</project>
```

`pom.xml` for `service` (simplified, a lot is excluded)

```xml
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>  
    <name>service</name>  
    <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>  
            <artifactId>common-module</artifactId>  
            <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>  
            <version>2.4.5-SNAPSHOT</version>  
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Note 1**: I have a workaround where I can adjust the library settings within IntelliJ and force it to use the correct jar file, but this feels very hacky and unsustainable to me.

**Note 2**: I've tried changing the `<updatePolicy>` value in my `settings.xml` to `never` and other values, but it seems to have had no effect. This was suggested in other posts I've read before asking here.

```xml
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>Archiva Managed Snapshot Repository</name>
                <url>http://internal.url/repository/snapshots</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
```

Comment: This is just for local dev presumably? When I want to be sure I'm only picking up stuff that's local, I just install with a name for the version that will never make it to a real repo, e.g. "michael-1.2.3", and use that in the dependent project. In fact, all our projects use `${revision}` for their version, which is initialized in `<properties>` to a default value = `localdev-SNAPSHOT`; CI overrides it to a real version like `1.2.3`. Achieves the same as what I described, but you never have to touch it.

Comment: Is this a multi module build??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force Maven to use my local repository rather than going out to remote repos to retrieve artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548395/how-do-i-force-maven-to-use-my-local-repository-rather-than-going-out-to-remote)

Comment: @Micheal, yes it is for local dev only, and yes I could go down that route of a different value for version such as `localdev-SNAPSHOT`.
@khmarbaise, yes, multi module but also multi project. I don't have the option of changing that setup unfortunately.
@life888888, I tried changing the `updatePolicy` as referenced in that answer, but it seems like it never took effect. My `common-module` that was locally built never got picked up even though it was the newest package (built seconds earlier)

Comment: If you have a multi module build that has to work otherwise your setup is wrong... That something is tried to get from cache or alike implies something is wrong... Best is to test a multi module setup via the following steps: Try to build on plain command line (outside of IDE): `mvn clean verify -Dmaven.repo.local=$(pwd)/.repo` that should work withou any issue which I doubt... furthermore if you are using `${revision}` in your project version or parents you have to use `flatten-maven-plugin` ...(https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)